# Set player UUID (world owner) in multiplayer

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

### Problem:

I have singeplayer world which I moved to multiplayer server (online-mode=false).

But when I log in, I have different UUID, so all my dogs are not mine anymore and my villager discounts are lost too.

When I log in with online-mode=true, I get my skin and UUID is correct.

Using minecraft 1.16.3.

### What I tried:

https://www.reddit.com/r/admincraft/comments/29vugf/converting_an_onlinemode_server_to_an_offlinemode/
(answer from `veubeke`)

I took files from playerdata, renamed them with player names and for my file with my name I changed the UUID to the correct one (with help of NBTExplorer).
Those files I moved to folder named `players`.

I also tried to change dogs owner uuid, but it had no affect (through /execute and /data commands).

### What I need:

When logging in with online-mode=false - I need for myself to get 'online' UUID and for other players, to stay it as it is.

Comment: I have a similar problem. The only possible solution I found would be to use https://github.com/Radon8472/PHP-NBT-Decoder-Encoder and rewrite all `*.mca` below the `region` folder and replace the UUIDs in all dogs there. But till now I did create a script to do this.

Your Idea to use your online UUID when you are in offline mode will not work, because in offline mode UUIDs are created with an algorythm from your username.

Comment: Maybe try starting the server with --singleplayer USERNAME. The wiki doesn't say what it does but I'm pretty sure it treats the player with USERNAME as the singleplayer player.